# If page footer data overflows, then it should print in the next page's footer

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to print a text-field, which has more than 4000 characters.

I put the text-field in the page's footer and try to print it, but when the data overflows it's not printing in next page's footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the footer's 'Position Type' to 'Float' in its properties.

It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check the page size in your report properties. 
Too big pages can be cutted to the printers page size like a Letter or A4.
In this case the "overhead" will not be printed, becouse it is not really a new page for your report.

If your report ist longer than your paper, you can try:

- to adapt your reports page size to printers page size
- to scale the report to printers page size during printing

I hope it helps :)